# Are all JDBC Plugins Compatible?

Tags: java, jdbc

This is just a theoretical question, but I am building a program that gets data from Facebook using the CDATA JDBC Plugin, I wanted to know if all JDBC Plugins have the same syntax. For example, if I just change the JAR file for the driver to a Twitter one, and change the names of the tables and columns I am accessing, would it still work?

By a plugin I mean a driver, also, to put it more clearly, if I was developing a MySQL app and switched from the stock Connector/J Driver to the CData driver, would I need to change the code?

Comment: What exactly do you consider a "JDBC plugin" to be? The JDBC specification (and API) does not have a concept of "plugins".

Comment: What do you mean with syntax? The methods of JDBC are defined by the specification, but the queries used might have different dialects.

Answer (score 1):

Until the underlying schema where you store remains same, the use of JDBC driver will yield the same result.
`Note: Twitter/FB... both has to support the JDBC Model...`
However, if you have changes in Drivers, you can consider using `ApacheMetamodel` [Link for reference](http://metamodel.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is a standard that has been established and vetted over the years. As long as the drivers you're working with are written to that standard (which as a CData employee, I can say that ours are) you can expect your code referencing a JDBC driver to be essentially identical, regardless of the manufacturer of the driver or the data source you're connecting to.

```
//optional, register the driver with the DriverManager
Class.forName(myDriverName).newInstance();

//obtain a Connection instance from the DriverManager
Connection conn = null;
try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myJDBCurl);

  //execute a select query
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  Result rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT foo FROM bar");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  //handle any errors
}
```

As you can see, the code to utilize the JDBC driver can be generalized with variables to use any driver or to use different connections under a single driver (if, for instance, you wanted to connect to different Facebook accounts).

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is an interesting standard. It was intentionally designed to load the driver at run-time, so no vendor classes are used during compilation.

It also has some JDBC own mechanisms for schema data (DatabaseMetaData), and for such things as doing an `INSERT` with an autoincrement key, and retrieving that key (`getGeneratedKeys`).

However the SQL is far from standardized by vendor, despite standardisation efforts. For example just getting the first 10 rows.

Unfortunately the visionaries of JDBC seem no longer to exist.
But it a sound basis for professional usage.